# Compiler doesn't recognize lstat even with the #include's

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 ...
 lstat(name, &st);
 ...
```

I am using CodeBlocks to write a C program. All the other includes work fine. I checked online and lstat requires the three includes listed at the top of the code, but I still get the error message *warning: implicit declaration of function 'lstat'* when I try to compile. I do not know what is wrong. If I need to include any extra information to get help, please say.

Comment: Can you provide a short compilable example? http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 8):

According to `lstat(2)`:

Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

```
   lstat():
       _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
       || /* Since glibc 2.10: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
```

This means you need to define one of these feature test macros to use `lstat(2)`.

So choose one of those feature test macros that makes sense to your code, such as `_BSD_SOURCE`, and define it in the very beginning (before you include any header file) of your source file, or you could define it on the compiler command line, such as `-D_BSD_SOURCE` for `gcc`.

Answer (score 4):

lstat() is not compliant with strict ANSI standard.You should use your compiler flags from 
-std=c99 to  -std=gnu99 . This would include all the Unix based system.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The effect of including `<sys/stat. h>` is outside the scope of ANSI/ISO C, so there's no reason it can't provide its core functionality even with `-ansi`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: I don't disagree, but a quick experiment shows that a simple program calling `lstat` elicits a warning with `-std=c99`, but compiles without error with `-std=gnu99`. But the OP still needs to (a) show us a complete example, and (b) tell us exactly how {,s}he compiled it.